# How many variatons of winners are there in 15 1vs1 matchs

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinations, gambling

I am trying to find a program or some way to show me every variation of winners from just 5 matchs of 1vs1.
I think there should be 900 variation i just need a way to see it all written  down ..
For example
A1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1 g1 h1 j1/
A2 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1 g1 h1 j1/
A1 b2 c1 d1 e1 f1 g1 h1 j1

Is there any kind of program that does this?

Comment: I just want to pick every possible arrangement of winners for just the first 15 matchs

Comment: My example didn't come correctly

Comment: So if I have 30 players. 15 games with 2 players each game. 1 winner per game. There are 15 winners. Now if I want to pick all 15 winners. How many variations are there of possibility that they could win

Comment: There are $2^{15} = 32,768$ possible outcomes since there are two possible winners for each of the $15$ matches.

Comment: It's not clear just what you want to count. Please [edit] the question to show us everything when there are just two matches and four players. List all the matches and all the winners and any other lists that matter to you and tell us which list you care about. Do this by editing the question, not in comments.

Comment: What do the letters and numbers in your examples mean? What do the changes in the 3 patterns mean?